# What do I have to do with Eclipse Uncaught Exception -1

Tags: java, minecraft

I am currently trying to create a Minecraft Mod for the 1.16.5.
I am using Eclipse. Everytime I try to run my project it doesn't work and the Console only gives me this wall of text:

```
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]: net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.InvalidModFileException: Missing required field modid in dependency (main)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModInfo$ModVersion.lambda$new$0(ModInfo.java:190)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModInfo$ModVersion.<init>(ModInfo.java:190)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModInfo.lambda$null$6(ModInfo.java:94)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" [17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:  at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModInfo.lambda$new$7(ModInfo.java:95)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModInfo.<init>(ModInfo.java:92)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileInfo.lambda$new$2(ModFileInfo.java:94)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileInfo.<init>(ModFileInfo.java:95)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser.modsTomlParser(ModFileParser.java:62)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFileParser.readModList(ModFileParser.java:46)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModFile.identifyMods(ModFile.java:113)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.moddiscovery.ModDiscoverer.discoverMods(ModDiscoverer.java:121)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLLoader.beginModScan(FMLLoader.java:216)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.fml.loading.FMLServiceProvider.runScan(FMLServiceProvider.java:107)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServiceDecorator.runScan(TransformationServiceDecorator.java:114)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.lambda$runScanningTransformationServices$8(TransformationServicesHandler.java:115)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.runScanningTransformationServices(TransformationServicesHandler.java:116)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at cpw.mods.modlauncher.TransformationServicesHandler.initializeTransformationServices(TransformationServicesHandler.java:63)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:76)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:66)
[17:12:25] [main/INFO] [STDERR/]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:-1]:     at net.minecraftforge.userdev.LaunchTesting.main(LaunchTesting.java:105)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Well this looks like the important bit: "Missing required field modid in dependency" - I don't know anything about Minecraft mods, but I would check all your dependencies and make sure there's a modid for all of them...

Comment: check file `mods.toml` (`src/main/.../META-INF/`) some `dependencies.` entry is missing the `modId` (or incorrect) I think both `"minecraft"` and `"forge"` must be present

Answer (score 0):

I was able to *reproduce* your error easily by removing a modId-Entry in one of the dependency lines. I got the exact same error. 
*Make sure that you didn't accidently deleted the modId entry under the [[dependencies.yourmodid]] elements* (as **@user15244370** suggested in the comments). 
**Also, make sure to always refresh your project** if you modified files outside of Eclipse (by right-clicking your project in the package explorer and clicking on "Refresh"), or else your modifications might not appear (when I was really new in minecraft modding, this was a huge source of problems, and it sometimes still is for me today).